# A game theory winning strategy problem

Tags: game-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Consider the following game. The rules are as follows: There is an unlimited supply of identical coins, each with radius s > 0. Each player takes turns to place coins inside a shaded region. The coins cannot overlap, and they must lie entirely inside the shaded region. The first player who cannot put down a coin will lose the game. Consider the shaded region B, which is an annulus bounded by two circles with radius r(> s) and R(> 3r) respectively. Is it true that one of two players has a winning strategy ?

[image]

I know that there is not a winning strategy, but how to prove it?

Comment: You *know* that "there is not a winning strategy"? What do you mean by that? Do you mean that neither player has a winning strategy? ***How do you know that?*** It seems obvious to me that one player or the other must have a winning strategy.

Comment: By the way, did you ***delete*** your first draft of this question and post it as a new question? Why did you do that instead of editing your question?

Comment: I know that by the Zermelo's Theorem, once the radius r and R is fixed, there must be some winning strategy for someone. But I think that in this problem, r and R is not fixed and I don't think that a certain player will definitely win no matter what r and R is. Therefore, I mean that we cannot ensure that which one has a winning strategy. Is that true?

Comment: Sorry but I delete it by mistake and I'm not so familiar with the website.

Comment: By the way, I think the position of the small circle might also influence the strategy.

Comment: If it's a *standard* annulus, with the circles of radius $r$ and $R$ sharing a common center, then the second player has a winning strategy, simply by "mirroring" whatever the first player does.  For certain nonstandard annuli, the first player has a winning strategy.

Comment: **I know that by the Zermelo's Theorem, once the radius r and R is fixed, there must be some winning strategy for someone.** Good, but you should have put that *in your question*. You should tell us what you know about the problem, so we know we don't have to explain Zermelo's theorem to you.

Comment: Got that, thank you for your kindly help.